# Check whether sum of two list members can be found in another list

Tags: python

In this program I have written, so far you get a set of numbers. You choose the number of dice you would like to play with. Every turn you roll the num of dice, and choose two of them to sum to one of the numbers in your original number set.

I am trying to make it so if there are no possible numbers to sum together that would eliminate a number from the original number set. It will say "sorry no possible solutions" and skip the turn.

Eventually I will add the computer to vs and that's what it will skip too, but I would like to have this working first.

```
import random
lst_player = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
lst_cpu = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

num_dice = int(input("Enter the number of dice you would like to play with 3-5 : 
"))

def stars():
    count = 0
    for count in range(30):
        count += 1
        print("*", end=' ')
    print("")

stars()

print("Player set","    ",lst_player)
print("Computer set","  ",lst_cpu)

stars()

while lst_player or lst_cpu != []:

    print("")

    roll = input("Player turn, enter 'e' to roll : ")
    dice_lst = []
    if roll == "e":
        for e in range(num_dice):
            d_lst = random.randint(1,6)
            dice_lst.append(d_lst)
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue 

    while True:

        print("")
        print("You rolled", dice_lst)
        dice_choose = int(input("Choose a dice : "))
        dice_lst.remove(dice_choose)
        print("")
        print("You are left with", dice_lst)
        dice_choose1 = int(input("Choose a dice : "))
        dice_lst.remove(dice_choose1)
        print("")

        sum1 = dice_choose + dice_choose1
        if sum1 not in lst_player:
            dice_lst.append(dice_choose)
            dice_lst.append(dice_choose1)
            print("You have made an invalid choice")
            continue

        print(dice_choose, "+", dice_choose1, "sums to", sum1)
        print(sum1, "will be removed")
        print("")

        lst_player.remove(sum1)
        break

    stars()

    print("Player set","    ",lst_player)
    print("Computer set","  ",lst_cpu)

    stars()

else:
    print("You have won or lost. IDK yet.")
```

**My question:** 
I am trying to make it so if there are no possible numbers to sum together that would eliminate a number from the original number set. It will say "sorry no possible solutions" and skip the turn.

Example:

```
dice_lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst_player = [6, 7, 8]
```

as neither `1 + 2 => 3` nor `1 + 3 => 4` nor `2 + 3 => 5` can be found in `lst_player` I'd like to print `"sorry no possible solutions"`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It's best to phrase your question very explicitly and to post the shortest possible question 

 I  had to read several times until I think I understood what you want.

Is that your question?

I'd like to detect the case where any sum of two of a list of `n` dice cannot be found in a given list.

Example:
`dice_lst = [1, 2, 3]` but `lst_player = [6, 7, 8]`

as neither `1 + 2 => 3` nor `1 + 3 => 4` nor `2 +3 => 5` can be found in `lst_player`

I'd like to print "sorry no possible solutions"

Comment: Yeah sorry next time I will make it shorter.

Comment: Also things to look at:
you had to validate that `dice_choose` has a valid value if not your script will break.

same fore `dice_choose1` and for `roll` 
It's quite frustrating if one accidentally hits the wrong number and the script aborts.

Will write the answer to your question soon.

Please note as well.

If people give you feedback or commentsm it can be a good idea to edit your question and adapt it such, that it is easier to read / understand.

In fact writing an easy to understand question is quite difficult, but you'll get the hang of it

Comment: your question got down-voted. I'd adapt the question a little in order to avoid further down votes.

Comment: By the way. The singular of dice is die Also the function stars() can be simplified. First there is no reason for the line `count = 0` and `count += 1`. The line `for count in range(30):` counts already from 0 to 29. Further the same is achieved by just writing `print("*" * 30)`

Comment: Either somebody deleted my comment or I myself did accidentally click on delete.
I wrote, that when I saw, that you got quite some down votes, I edited your answer to be easier to understand in order to avoid you're losing more points. Normally you should do this by yourself and not wait for others to do it. I though showing how a question can be improved might be constructive.

In any case it would be good to get some reaction from you about my comments and my answers.

So far all I got from anybody participating is a down vote, not even one comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well this is what you you're looking for:

This is not the most elegant solution, but one that is rather easy to understand
and doesn't require knowledge of any other python modules.

you just try out all combinations of two dice, calculate the sum and if you can find a sum, you return `True` (and stop looking for other solutions)
otherwise (if you have tried all combinations and you found nothing)
you return `False`)

Now you can use this function in your code to check whether you want to ask the user which dice to choose or whether to immediately `continue` the loop

```
def can_remove_a_number(thrown_dice, remaining_numbers):
    """
    checks whether the sum of two dice out of thrown_dice
    can be found in remaining_numbers
    """
    for idx1 in range(len(thrown_dice) - 1):
        for idx2 in range(idx1 + 1,  len(thrown_dice)):
            # next line for debugging only
            print("trying die %d and die %d" % (idx1, idx2))
            sum_ = thrown_dice[idx1] + thrown_dice[idx2]
            # next line for debugging only
            print("sum = ", sum_)
            if sum_ in remaining_numbers:
                return True
    return False
```

and for testing:

```
print("*" * 30)
print(can_remove_a_number([1,2,2], [5,6,7]))
print("*" * 30)
print(can_remove_a_number([1,2,2], [4,5,6,7]))
print("*" * 30)

# or if you want to write a test
# assert <expression> breaks if expression is not True
assert not can_remove_a_number([1,2,2], [5,6,7])
print("*" * 30)

assert can_remove_a_number([1,2,2], [4,5,6,7])
print("*" * 30)
```

In fact now a less manual solution.
Just use https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

```
from itertools import combinations

def can_remove_a_number(thrown_dice, remaining_numbers):
    for dice in combinations(thrown_dice, 2):
        sum_ = sum(dice)
        if sum_ in remaining_numbers:
            return True
    return False
```

Or if you heard about list comprehensions / comprehensions ( https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html ) :

```
def can_remove_a_number(thrown_dice, remaining_numbers):
    for sum_ in (sum(dice) for dice in combinations(thrown_dice, 2)):
        if sum_ in remaining_numbers:
            return True
    return False
```

or with another comprehension

```
def can_remove_a_number(thrown_dice, remaining_numbers):
    for found in (sum(dice) in remaining_numbers 
                  for dice in combinations(thrown_dice, 2)):
        if found:
            return True
    return False
```

or you combine with the any function ( https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#any )

```
def can_remove_a_number(thrown_dice, remaining_numbers):
    return any(sum(dice) in remaining_numbers 
               for dice in combinations(thrown_dice, 2))
```

Comment: fixed 3 typos and added *test code*
If you write some tests, then it is easier to midify / optimize / refactor your function and see if it still behaves the same way.

My 2 mini tests are probable not sufficient, but you get the idea

Comment: added step by step shorter solutions, however they require a little more python knowledge to be understandable.

I added links

Comment: Sorry. How would I do that?

Comment: I never knew there was an accepted button.

Comment: I think I did it. This is what it says. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: I just want to thank you for making such a detailed explanation to my problem. You even did it like 5 different ways. I was stuck on this for days and thanks to you I can finally continue with my game.

Comment: Ah OK I see. I think you did an upvote and not an accept. 
Well normally you should see next to my answer some kind of greyed out checkmark. 
Look here at a screen shot: https://imgur.com/eVPZ1Sl

Directly from https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
"To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." 
Enjoy coding your game and using python. 



Happy coding!!

Comment: Now I found an SO answer explaining how to accept an answer. Probably better than my explanation:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Please note for accepting an answer you will also get +2 reputation.

In fact if you have some old questions for which you got a useful answer you can even now retroactively accept an answer. Getting your reputation up a little can be helpful in some small ways.

Comment: One last thought. If you do not see the check mark, then it is perhaps because your question was closed. However I don't know I didn't see anything saying, that answers to closed questions cannot be accepted.

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer

Comment: It's the least I can do seeing all the examples you gave me.